# Web scraped elements returned aren't the values I'm looking for

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver, driver

Using selenium and phantomJS I'm trying to webscrape the track names from this horse racing statistics site. I can't seem to get the actual names within the elements I'm hunting for. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
site = "https://www.drf.com/live_odds"

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(my_directory)
driver.get(site)

trackname = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="titleTrack"]')

num_of_tracks = len(trackname)
print(num_of_tracks)

for i in range(num_of_tracks):
    print(trackname[i])

driver.close()
```

Returns this:

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345793")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345794")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345795")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345796")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345797")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345798")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345799")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345800")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345801")>
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="4286dc50-aa79-11e9-80c7-21f36addf5ef", element=":wdc:1563577345802")>
```

10 of them, I think for the 10 track names there.

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page and edit your question to improve it.
Good questions tend to receive quick, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 0):

You have found the web elements.  Now, you need to get the text from these elements.  Try this:

```
for i in range(num_of_tracks):
    print(trackname[i].text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="titleTrack">
    <a href="/live_odds/winodds/track/AUS-AUC/AUS/5/D">AUS-Flemington</a>
</span>
```

title is included in `<a>` tag. so i tried xpath with `'//span[@class="titleTrack"]/a'`

then text value access `element.text`

```
for i in range(num_of_tracks):
    print(trackname[i].text)
```